# C++ Windows get registry value inconsistent returns

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a simple C++ program to grab a Windows registry value on a 64 bit machine.
The problem is it only works for about 50% of the registry's and for the other half "ret" does not return ERROR_SUCCESS(0).

My question is to why I am getting these inconsistent returns and also when I attempt to make the path longer than two directories it also break. 
ex.

```
keypath = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Perl\\ASDF");
```

Here is my code.

```
LPCTSTR keypath = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Perl");
HKEY key = NULL;
LONG ret = ERROR_SUCCESS;
DWORD BufferSize = TOTALBYTES;
DWORD cbData;
DWORD dwRet;
DWORD type;
char registry[256] = {'\0'};

ret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keypath, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);

PPERF_DATA_BLOCK PerfData = (PPERF_DATA_BLOCK) malloc( BufferSize );
cbData = BufferSize;

if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwRet = RegQueryValueEx( key,
                         TEXT("BinDir"),
                         NULL,
                         &type,
                         (LPBYTE) PerfData,
                         &cbData );
    RegCloseKey(key);
    printf("\nFinal buffer size is %d\n", BufferSize);
    int i = 0;
    while ((*PerfData).Signature[i] != NULL)
    {
        registry[i] = (char)(*PerfData).Signature[i];
        i++;
    }
    printf("registery: %s\n", registry);
}
```

editing in fixes.

Comment: What *does* it return if not `ERROR_SUCCESS`?

Comment: it usually return ret = 2. Even if I double check to make sure that everything is spelled correctly

Comment: I'm kind of wondering why there are three backslashes in the top one instead of two.

Comment: fixed it, I initially had it as plain text so in order to get two backslashes you have to put three.

Comment: Is it a 64bits build?

Comment: Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which means you are trying to open a key that does not actually exist. Also, `RegOpenKey()` is a deprecated 16-bit API function, you should be using `RegOpenKeyEx()` instead, which you need to do anyway if you need to [access alternate 32bit and 64bit Registry views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks that works. `ret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keypath, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key);` However it still fails it I try to extend my `keypath` past two directories

Comment: "two directories": Maybe you are then trying to "open" a value, not a key.

Comment: Lets say Im trying to get value of Oracle->ODACHelp->this link for reference [link](http://i.imgur.com/MMQWmAK.png?1)

Comment: If you are in the HKLM realm you may not have permission to modify it. HKCU is a realm what you have surely permission for.

Comment: Wow, I just tested it with HKCU and its working perfectly, do you know how to get it permissions to work for HKLM

Comment: Since you are on a 64-bit system, make sure you are attempting to access the correct Registry key. If Oracle is 32-bit, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Oracle` is likely mapped to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle`. If Oracle is 64-bit, but your app is 32-bit, then Oracle will be using `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Oracle` but your app will be trying to access `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle` instead. That's where the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flags of `RegOpenKeyEx()` start coming into play. Also, use SysInternals Process Monitor to watch Registry activity in real-time to what is really going on.